# Spacebar as Play/Pause a game or animated flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

I'm new to flash and I'm really a starter because our professor didn't teach us how to code a flash

I made a Pong game that I learned from the internet, which is already moving from the start
I want to stop it at first, then when I hit spacebar it will play, and if I hit spacebar again it will pause.
Would appreciate if someone help me :)

I'm using AS3 btw

here is the code

```html
var ballSpeedX:int = -3;
var ballSpeedY:int = -2;
var cpuPaddleSpeed:int = 3;
var playerScore:int = 0;
var cpuScore:int = 0;

init();

function init():void
{
 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

function calculateBallAngle(paddleY:Number, ballY:Number):Number
{
 var ySpeed:Number = 5 * ( (ballY-paddleY) / 25 );
 //trace(ySpeed);
 
 return ySpeed;
}

function updateTextFields():void
{
 playerScoreText.text = ("Player Score: " + playerScore);
 cpuScoreText.text = ("CPU Score: " + cpuScore);
}

function loop(e:Event):void
{
 if( playerPaddle.hitTestObject(ball) == true ){
  if(ballSpeedX < 0){
   ballSpeedX *= -1;
   ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(playerPaddle.y, ball.y);
  }
  
 } else if(cpuPaddle.hitTestObject(ball) == true ){
  if(ballSpeedX > 0){
   ballSpeedX *= -1;
   ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(cpuPaddle.y, ball.y);
  }
  
 }
 
 if(cpuPaddle.y < ball.y - 10){
  cpuPaddle.y += cpuPaddleSpeed;
  
 } else if(cpuPaddle.y > ball.y + 10){
  cpuPaddle.y -= cpuPaddleSpeed;
 }
  
 
 playerPaddle.y = mouseY;
 
 //check if top of paddle is above top of screen
 if(playerPaddle.y - playerPaddle.height/2 < 0){ 
  playerPaddle.y = playerPaddle.height/2;
 
 //check if bottom of paddle is below bottom of screen
 } else if(playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height/2 > stage.stageHeight){
  playerPaddle.y = stage.stageHeight - playerPaddle.height/2;
 }
 
 ball.x += ballSpeedX;
 ball.y += ballSpeedY;
 
 //because the ball's position is measured by where its CENTER is...
 //...we need add or subtract half of its width or height to see if that SIDE is hitting a wall
 
 //first check the left and right boundaries
 if(ball.x <= ball.width/2){ //check if the x position of the left side of the ball is less than or equal to the left side of the screen, which would be 0
  ball.x = ball.width/2; //then set the ball's x position to that point, in case it already moved off the screen
  ballSpeedX *= -1; //and multiply the ball's x speed by -1, which will make it move right instead of left
  cpuScore ++; //increase cpuScore by 1
  updateTextFields();
 } else if(ball.x >= stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2){ //check to see if the x position of it's right side is greater than or equal to the right side of the screen, which would be 550
  ball.x = stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2; //and set the x position to that, in case it already moved too far of the right side of the screen
  ballSpeedX *= -1; //multiply the x speed by -1 so that the ball is now moving left
  playerScore++; //increase playerScore by 1
  updateTextFields(); 
 }
 
 //now we do the same with the top and bottom of the screen
 if(ball.y <= ball.height/2){ //if the y position of the top of the ball is less than or equal to the top of the screen
  ball.y = ball.height/2; //like we did before, set it to that y position...
  ballSpeedY *= -1; //...and reverse its y speed so that it is now going down instead of up
  
 } else if(ball.y >= stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2){ //if the bottom of the ball is lower than the bottom of the screen
  ball.y = stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2; //reposition it
  ballSpeedY *= -1; //and reverse its y speec so that it is moving up now
  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your player input code looks like though, but you can also have it that when it is paused you can set a pause flag and later ignore any input based on that flag in your key or mouse input event handlers.

As for the actual game logic, it looks like your ENTER_FRAME event handler handles most of it, so you could add a check for the pause lag before deciding to execute the rest of the logic in there.

An alternative is to remove your ENTER_FRAME event handler entirely to stop the game from running, then adding it back in when you want to resume.